# Save image from drawable folder to user phone gallery

Tags: android, uri, mediastore

I've tried to save and image file (PNG) from the drawable folder in the app to the gallery folder on the phone. The idea is that the user will click on a button and it will save the image on the imageview to the user phone's gallery (not sd card or any other external storage). My code as follows;

```
   public class MainActivity extends Activity {

      ImageView imageview;
      Button button;
      Drawable drawable;
      Bitmap bitmap;
      String ImagePath;
      Uri URI;

      @Override
      protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  .....

     Button b_img = (Button) findViewById( R.id.imageb );

    b_img.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

        drawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.b1);

        bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)drawable).getBitmap();

            ImagePath = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(
                    getContentResolver(),
                    bitmap,
                    "demo_image",
                    "demo_image"
            );

            URI = Uri.parse(ImagePath);

      .....
```

For some reason, there is an error with URI = Uri.parse(Imagepath) (line 413). My logcat as follows

```
    V/FA: Using measurement service
    V/FA: Connecting to remote service
    E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: com.shex.testapp, PID: 1969
              java.lang.NullPointerException: uriString
                  at android.net.Uri$StringUri.<init>(Uri.java:467)
                  at android.net.Uri$StringUri.<init>(Uri.java:457)
                  at android.net.Uri.parse(Uri.java:429)
                  at com.shex.testapp.MainActivity$5.onClick(MainActivity.java:413)
                  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
                  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
                  at       android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
                  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Where is `uriString`?

Comment: do a null check if `(URI!=null){..}` after `URI = Uri.parse(ImagePath);` image path seems null

Comment: `from the drawable folder in the app to the gallery folder on the phone.`. Gallery folder? Where would that be? Never seen one.

Comment: `it will save the image on the imageview to the user phone's gallery`. Well that is a different source now. An image in an image view is not an image from drawable folder. Quite confusing.

Comment: What you are doing is trying to save a bitmap to the media store. You are not even mentioning this.